# How to add SAP component to Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mule, netweaver

I have upgraded Anypoint Studio and when I try to find SAP component it got disappeared. Before upgrade it was there. I tried to install from Mule given link by going to help -> install new software but I could not find the component but it is there in Exchange.

How can I download again?

Even I didn't find any SAP-related transformers.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things you can check.

- When you go to the Install New Software there is a checkbox that says "Show already installed items" if you check it you can see if SAP is shown as if it is already installed even if you can not see it in the Palette
- If it is installed and you can not see it, can you open the Error log view (Window > Show View > Other > Error Log ) and see if there is any exception thrown there mentioning anything about the SAP Connector ? can you post the Exception?
- Did you change the runtime version of your project? what runtime version are you using? Just to see if the version of the runtime you are using is compatible with the version of the SAP Connector.